# Wired internet connection lost 5 min after reboot

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager

The wired internet connection is dropped approximately 5 min after a reboot. Running `sudo dhclient` restores the connection. Once restored, the connection is ok until next reboot.

I think the problem started after upgrade to 15.04 (but could have been 15.10).

Before the internet connection is lost (< 5 min after reboot):

```
ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:b6:54:a6:69:98  
          inet addr:192.168.51.181  Bcast:192.168.51.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9eb6:54ff:fea6:6998/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6763 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3805 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3932488 (3.9 MB)  TX bytes:517066 (517.0 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:ef100000-ef120000
```

After it is lost (> 5 min after reboot):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:b6:54:a6:69:98  
          inet6 addr: fe80::9eb6:54ff:fea6:6998/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:61238 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9149 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11382757 (11.3 MB)  TX bytes:1442442 (1.4 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:ef100000-ef120000
```

Restored (after `sudo dhclient`):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:b6:54:a6:69:98  
          inet addr:192.168.51.181  Bcast:192.168.51.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9eb6:54ff:fea6:6998/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:69929 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13905 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:17527607 (17.5 MB)  TX bytes:2203444 (2.2 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:ef100000-ef120000
```

Relevant `lspci -nnk` output:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM [8086:153a] (rev 05)
        DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1905]
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
```